# Git branching and switching back to master is ahead?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have code that is working pretty good and created a branch to make some significant changes on my work computer with `git checkout -b messaging`.  I committed my partially completed work and pushed it to my remote repository with `git push origin messaging`.  Now that I'm home, I did a `git pull origin messaging` and am on that branch, but I want to switch back to master, but `git checkout master` gives me the following message:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

and all of the files from my modification of the `messaging` branch are there.  `git status` informs me that I am on branch `master`, but that my branch is ahead of `origin/master` by 1 commit.  I've figured out I can get to my *real* master two ways:

```
git checkout origin/master
git checkout master~1
```

However I'm confused about why this is happening, and I want to make sure that my changes to `master` won't affect the `messaging` branch and vice-versa.  What I want to do is make `origin/master` my local `master` as well and keep `messaging` in its separate branch.  Did I do something wrong to make `master` point to the `messaging` commit on my home computer?  At this point I want to have two completely isolated branches.

Thinking about it more, when I did `git pull origin messaging` I was on my `master` branch, did that actually merge the `messaging` branch into my local `master`?  If so, what should I have done (create local `messaging` branch and pull into that?) and how can I point my local `master` back to the commit without the `messaging` changes?

Comment: I just did a 'git reset --hard origin/master' and I think that might have fixed my problem.  I would still like information on exactly what I did wrong to avoid it in the future and if that is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, `git pull`... I don't like `git pull`; all it does is confuse people. So what happened?

Everything up until you when home and ran `git pull origin messaging` was fine. If you run `git branch -av` you'll see that `origin/master` and `origin/messaging` point to the commits you want.

So, what did the pull do?

`git pull` is really just a wrapper for a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. `git fetch` is easy; it just collected information on any snapshots the remote (specified by `origin`) had that you didn't have locally. In this case, one commit and branch named `origin/messaging`. Then, the pull ran `git merge origin/messaging` which merged the `origin/messaging` branch into whatever branch you currently had checked out (`master`). So, you unintentionally pulled the changes from `origin/messaging` into `master`.

Let's fix things up. First, put master back where it should be:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now, checkout a local branch called `messaging` based on your remote branch:

```
git checkout -b --track messaging origin/messaging
```

You can now continue to work on the `messaging` branch.

In the future, I recommend avoiding `git pull`. I find its semantics are confusing. Instead, run `git fetch` and then update each branch as you're interested in working on them with a merge or a rebase.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that 'git fetch' actually got all changes in all branches from the remote.  The picture I finally have is just of a sea of commits, with each commit pointing backwards to the one it was created from.  Also there are branches which are basically just pointer to a commit (and therefore the history of that commit).  I thought the initial clone was somehow looking at the master branch, but I guess it pulls all commits and branch pointers, but after that I need to specifically track any new remote branches.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it!

Answer (score 5):

I think you have answered your own question. From the manual for `git pull`:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

In other words, you pulled the remote 'messaging' branch into your local master branch.

This is a general danger of doing `git pull` without really understanding what it's doing. It is, in essence, a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, which is obviously not what you wanted in this case. What you probably want to do is `git fetch` followed by `git checkout --track origin/messaging`. This will create a local `messaging` branch which tracks the remote—this is probably the behavior you expect.

[This blog entry](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) by Mark Longair does a good job of explaining `git pull` and why you're often better off explicitly fetching and merging.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I upvoted you but thought Peter's was just a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your pull did a fetch and a merge of the branch into your master branch. And yes you are correct, you should have created a local messaging branch and pulled into that.

Consider breaking it down into the 2 commands `git fetch then git merge origin/XX` so that you are 100% clear as to what is happening.